# C++ using-declaration with enums: how to import all the enum items?

Tags: c++, enums, using

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate my question.

```
namespace N{
    enum E { A, B, C, D };
}

int main(){
    using N::E;
    E e = A; // syntax error: 'A' is not declared
}
```

The last line gives me a syntax error. I'd like to use the names `N::A`, `N::B`, `N::C` and `N::D` in the main function without the namespace qualifier `N::`. But I *don't* want to do the following two things

(1) I don't want to say `using namespace N`, because that would import *everything else* in N.

(2) I don't want say `using N::A`, `using N::B`, etc for every member of the enum. Because then if I want to modify the enum, I'll have to change my main function as well. Not to mention that the extra typing is tedious and error-prone.

I tried searching for an answer myself but couldn't. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For C++11 to C++17, if you can change the header where `E` is defined, try an [inline namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces).

```
namespace N {
    inline namespace Enums {
        enum E { A, B, C, D };
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace N::Enums;
    E e = A;
}
```

All the names in the inline namespace are visible in the enclosing namespace `N` as though the inline namespace weren't there, but this allows you to import all the names and just the names you want.

---

Update: C++20 introduces the `using enum` syntax to alias all enumerators of an enum type (but not the type itself). So this example could be

```
namespace N{
    enum E { A, B, C, D };
}

int main() {
    using N::E;
    using enum N::E;
    E e = A;
}
```

Comment: Now that's clever!

Comment: @aschelpler Your answer does seem to be a solution to my problem. I'm wondering what the `inline' keyword does to a namespace though. I tried to compile the code without the inline and that works just fine.

Comment: Without the `inline`, you can no longer say `N::E` or `N::A` in a context that doesn't have that using directive.  I figured you wouldn't want to force everyone to use it.

Comment: @aschepler I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a qualified name

```
E e = E::A;
```

For example

```
namespace N {
    enum E { A, B, C, D };
}

int main() 
{
    using N::E;
    E e = E::A;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Amadeus I guess he does not want to use the name of the namespace with enumerators.

Comment: @Amadeus He made a typo. E is not a namespace.:)

Comment: Thanks Amadeus. I was going to say the same. I'm wondering if there's a way other than what I mentioned for (1) and (2) in my question.

Comment: @Vlad OK. I just edited my question to fix the typo.

Comment: @HazySmoke It is a good idea to use the name of the enumeration before enumerators.:)